# Could a magnetorquer be used in orbit around Mars?

Tags: mars, magnetic-field, magnetorquer

One way to align a spacecraft into a certain manner while in orbit around a body is the use a [Magnetorquer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetorquer). Does Mars have enough of a magnetic field to allow such a device to operate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, a magnetorquer would be useless in orbit around Mars.

Mars has a surface field strength of maybe a few tens of nanoteslas. That's less of a magnetic field strength than a cassette tape. To make things worse, there isn't one single magnetic field, but a collection of weak remnant fields. Mars used to have a global magnetic field a few billion years ago, but today the remaining local fields barely even cover their relatively small areas.

**Sources:**

- [Mars: Magnetic Field and Magnetosphere - Luhmann and Russell](http://www-ssc.igpp.ucla.edu/personnel/russell/papers/mars_mag/)
- [Orders of magnitude (magnetic field) - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_%28magnetic_field%29)
- [MLS Picture of hte Day:T+18 Days: MAVEN - ExploreMars](http://www.exploremars.org/mls-picture-of-the-dayt18-days-maven)